# jQuery selector to not select dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, selector

I need a jQuery selector on a click event to not target dynamic content. I currently have this:

```
$('body:not(.sel)').on('click', function() {
```

So this should not run the function for the `.sel` class, but it is generated dynamically by jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current selector is looking for `body` elements that do not have the `.sel` class. I assume you instead mean that you want to select anything *within* the body which does not have the `.sel` class, in which case you need a space between the terms:

```
$('body :not(.sel)').on('click', function() {
  // your logic...  
});
```

That said, this is searching the entire DOM and adding a click handler to *every* relevant element. A better idea would be to attach a single handler on the `body` and check the class on the target as the event bubbles up:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('sel')) {
    // your logic...  
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't `e.target.classList.contains('sel')` similar to `$(this).hasClass("sel")`? The latter seems to be more better in terms of syntactic sugar, given that we are using jQuery.

Comment: Similar, but in this case `this` will be the `body`, not the clicked element. You could use `$(e.target).hasClass('sel')` if you preferred instead

Comment: Ahhh!!! Just saw it. You aren't ... But why? You could directly use `$('.sel').click()` or `$('body').not('.sel').click()`... Erm... Looks like I am asking you questions baselessly... 

Comment: Awesome, your second solution worked perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Because `$('body').not('sel')` is looking for `body` elements, not the elements *within* the body. Also `$('.sel').click()` is the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: @ElliottCoe no problem, glad to help

Comment: `$('body').on('click', ':not(.sel)', function() { }` would also work. `this` would be the clicked element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ahhh! I meant the code by Turnip above! ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code.

```
   $("html, body").not('.sel').click(function() {            
        alert('clicked');                        
    });
```

Try with this code.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work, I understand that if html is generated by jquery after the initial page load, that is has to be selected in a different way.

Comment: This is still looking for `html` and `body` elements which don't have the `sel` class, which makes little sense.

Comment: YOU should know the HTML.Here Its just an example.